# Grouping records by month

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to display the quantity, month, and year of a bunch of records grouped by month.  I am using the following query, and then using PHP to display the data.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), YEAR(award_date) AS award_date_year, MONTH(award_date) AS award_date_month
FROM projects_sell
GROUP BY YEAR(award_date),MONTH(award_date) ASC
```

Would I be better off using the following query, and using PHP to extract the month and year from the datetime?  I am strongly leaning towards doing so, and I will explain my interpretation of "better". I am only displaying 100 records at a time, so speed isn't a problem as long as both solutions are reasonable close.  My main reason is since I also at times display award_date as a formatted date, I wish to use PHP and not MySQL to format the date, and would like to keep all my formatting at one location.  The only reason I wouldn't use this approach would be if award_date ever didn't fall within the given month/year, or not using some sort of aggregating function on award_date causes some sort of problem.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), award_date
FROM projects_sell
GROUP BY YEAR(award_date),MONTH(award_date) ASC
```

Comment: Sure, if you don't care which award_date gets displayed!

Comment: @Strawberry.  I've been testing the later code, and the displayed award_date always is within the given year/month, and appears to be the one closest to the first day of the month.  Is this not always the case?

Comment: It cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @Strawberry.  Are you sure?  Do you know where it is documented?  GolezTrol's answer said it would, but he then recommended not doing so for reasons unknown to me.  Thank you

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Strawberry.  Thank you.  Struggling to see where the document states a returned date without an aggregate function might fall outside of the group by...

Comment: Well it's odd, don't you think, that they would bother providing such convoluted solutions to this problem, if the answer was really as simple as you seem to imagine! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry.  I hate it when things are not as I imagine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the year and month are extracted from `award_date`, `award_data` will always fall within that year and month.

But, since you're grouping by year and month alone, MySQL may pick any of the dates. So if there's an award for each day in may 2012, `award_date` can be any of those 30 dates in your resulting query. There's no way to tell which one it will be.

So I think it's cleaner to return the year and month in the query, since the query result is based on only those and not on an exact date.

Comment: Why do you think it is cleaner?  If I don't care about the day, only the month and year, will not `$date->format("F").' '.$date->format("Y")` always be correct?

Comment: But your query *will* return the day -a more or less random actually- and that is what is not 'clean' about it. But if you don't care about that, and you are fine with returning a piece of useless data to make it a tiny bit easier to display the other data, well sure, you can use the date. It will work, only you have to remember that the day is meaningless. I would vote against, because one day you forgot, or someone else is touching your code who didn't know in the first place. And that day, you have a website that says you won 50 awards on May 17. And worst, the next day it will say May 23.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP DATE() and store your value that passes through that function.

```
<?php
function myAwardDate($myDate)
{
  echo date("Y/m/d",$myDate) . "<br>";
  echo date("Y.m.d",$myDate) . "<br>";
  echo date("Y-m-d",$myDate);
}
?>
```

Pass your Award_Date String into this Date Function then you get any Date format.

Comment: So you recommend just passing a datetime which falls within the given month/year from MySQL to PHP?